# Stream gets returned before Future finishes

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, future

with this Function I load all News from firestore. I use the test-List for querying.

```
Stream<List<News>> getAllNews(List<String> test) {
    return _db
        .collection('news')
        .where('userRoleList', arrayContainsAny: test)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots() // oder .get um ein Future zu bekommen
        .map((query) => query.docs)
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.map((doc) => News.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  }
```

With this function, I pass the List to the previous function. But the problem is, that the Stream gets returned before the Future is finished.

```
Stream<List<News>> getAllTheNews() {
    getUser(_auth.currentUser.uid)
        .then((value) => userRoles = value.userRoleList);

    return _firestoreNewsService.getAllNews(userRoles);
  }
```

Is there any solution like returning the Stream after a delay or something else?

Thanky you

Comment: use `await` and remove `.then`

Comment: but then I need an async function and this wont work with Stream

Comment: exactly, but `async*` - see two versions: `Stream<int> foo() async* {
await Future.delayed(6.seconds);
yield* Stream.periodic(1.seconds, (i) => 10 * i).take(3);
}

Stream<int> foo2() {
StreamCompleter completer = StreamCompleter<int>();
Future.delayed(6.seconds).then((value) => completer.setSourceStream(
Stream.periodic(1.seconds, (i) => 10 * i).take(3)
));
return completer.stream;
}` - here you can go with `async* / await` or with `StreamCompleter / then` - i think that the first version is easier...

Comment: btw in the second version you can use `StreamController` too (instead of `StreamCompleter`)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Works fine!

Comment: I chose the first version with ```await```

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use async and await.

```
Stream<List<News>> getAllTheNews() async {
  final user = await getUser(_auth.currentUser.uid);
  final userRoles = user.userRoleList;

  return _firestoreNewsService.getAllNews(userRoles);
}
```